# Как добавить перевод строки в Android?

Tags: php, android, fcm

```
sendFCM('Уведомление', $account->getFullname().' хочет с вами подружиться.\n\nНажмите на уведомление, чтобы принять или отклонить заявку', $profileInfo['FCM'], '/account/notifications');
```

Пробовал **\n**, но пользователю так и приходит:

> Вася Пупкин хочет с вами подружиться.**\n\n**Нажмите на уведомление, чтобы принять или отклонить заявку

```
function sendFCM($title, $msg, $token, $urls = '') {
$url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
$fields = array (
        'to' => $token,
        'notification' => array (
                "body" => $msg,
                "title" => $title,
                "sound" => "default",
                'priority' => 'high',
                "icon" => "myicon",
        ),
        'data' => array (
                "url" => $urls
        )
);
$fields = json_encode($fields);
$headers = array (
        'Authorization: key=' . "122342",
        'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать html тэг

```
<br />
```

Посмотрите [ссылку](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382490/how-to-add-a-line-break-in-an-android-textview) может быть пригодиться

Comment: Пробовал. Тоже самое

Answer (score 0):

Обычный перевод в коде помог

```
sendFCM('Уведомление', $account->getFullname().' хочет с вами подружиться.

Нажмите на уведомление, чтобы принять или отклонить заявку', $profileInfo['FCM'], '/account/notifications');
```